# Mocha test, before(Each) not run?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to test my `mongoose` model like:

Todo = require "../../../app/todos/Todo"

```
describe "Todo", ->
describe "Basic CRUD", ->

    before: (done) ->
        console.log "In b4"
        Todo.remove {}, (err) ->
            console.log "removed"
            done err

    it "can be added to database", (done) ->
        todo = new Todo
            title: "New todo"
        todo.save (err) ->
            if !err
                Todo.find { title: "New todo" }, (err, docs) ->
                    docs.length.should.equal 1
                    done(err)
            else 
                done err
```

For some reason, `before` or `beforeEach` does not trigger, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your before i malformed.

should remove the ':' before before... Should be:

```
before (done) ->
     console.log 'In b4'
```